# MacOs. How can I ask access for System Events on every app?

Tags: swift, cocoa, applescript, entitlements

I need my Mac Swift app uses the System Events (via Applescript) to close any app that user adds to a list.
I see in my System Preferences a lot of apps having System Events access in Automation panel (e.g. 'Google's backup and sync' or 'Divvy'). How can I ask permissions for that?

Comment: You can't programmatically add items to the security preferences, the user needs to be involved.  In addition to the normal sandbox entitlements, your app needs to have a `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` key in its **Info.plist**, which is what the system uses to prompt the user when the app is first run.

Comment: Yes, I know is the user who must agree. I just wanted to know how to trigger that request. I'll try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

In Info.plist add the key `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` in Source Code view

```
<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs to control System Events</string>
```

or `Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description` in the popup menu in Property List view.

The `<string>` value is an arbitrary description.

Moreover in Xcode 11 where Hardened Runtime is enabled you have to check the `Apple Events` checkbox

Comment: How can we check if user has denied the permission or accepted it. Like, can we check if user has denied the permission and  we can manually show the popup again to let user know that this permission is compulsory ?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. The user gets an alert that the Apple Events could not be sent.

Answer (score 2):

I found a reliable way to ask Automation permission in my app.

Run a command to send System Event in shell use osascript, like this:

`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a"'`

If this is the first time you have sent System Event on user's computer, an authorization dialog will pop up by system.

If you want to check the Automation permission status, you can run the same script via NSAppleScript.

```objectivec
NSAppleScript *aScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *errorInfo;
[aScript executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
```

This code will silently fail in both cases when the first time sending System Event and when the authorization had denied. And the error code here will be -1743.

It should be noted that if the Accessibility permission is unauthorized, the error code here will be 1002. So first make sure that accessibility permissions are authorized.